# unnorm() function in R

Tags: r

Can anybody tell me how the unnorm() function works in the code below?
or help mw find documentation for unnorm()?

```
fitted_lstm <- model_lstm %>%
predict(x_tesla)

unn <- unnorm(fitted_lstm, min_x = min(residual_tesla), max_x = max(residual_tesla))
```

Thanks in advance
BR //Mathias

Comment: Does your code run?

Comment: If it does, can you type `?unnorm` or even `help('unnorm')`

Comment: `unnorm` is not a base R function. What packages are you using? Where does the function come from?

Comment: I have used many packages for decades and I've never run across unnorm() in any R package. Not even sure what, exactly the "un" would undo?